# Perl: Mail::IMAPClient with Gmail doesn't read new messages

Tags: perl, email, gmail, imap

After hours of searching, reading, and clawing for an answer, I come here to beg for help: 
 I am trying to write a client to read my Gmail with the Perl module [Mail::IMAPClient](http://search.cpan.org/~djkernen/Mail-IMAPClient/IMAPClient.pod). Everything so far is functional, and it works great, but when I try to get the number of emails in my "INBOX" folder, it doesn't give the correct number:

```
# initialize the IMAP object
$imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new ( Server => 'imap.gmail.com',
                                User => $username,
                                Password => $password,
                                Port => 993,
                                Ssl => 1,
                                Uid => 1 )
or die "Could not connect to server, terminating...\n";

# find which folder to read from
print "Mailboxes: ".  join(", ", $imap->folders) . "\n";
print "Folder to use: ";
chomp (my $folder = <STDIN>);
$imap->select($folder) or die "select() failed, terminating...\n";

# get message IDs and number of messages
my @msgIDs = $imap->search("ALL");
print scalar(@msgIDs) . " message(s) found in mailbox.\n";
```

When reading from my "INBOX" folder, assigning `@msgIDs` to the commands:

```
$imap->search("ALL");
$imap->messages;
$imap->message_count;
```

All result in the same number being said to be the number of messages (`1194`, to be exact) in the inbox, when there are actually `1149`.
After the number of messages is printed, the program continues with asking the user how many "headers" of recent messages they want to see (this means that if I put in "5", I would see the "Subject" and "From" header fields from the five newest messages). This code comes right after the previously shown code:

```
# get number of messages to read (so the entire inbox isn't looked at)
print "Read how many? ";
chomp (my $read_num = <STDIN>);

# read the original number of headers requested
&read_more (scalar(@msgIDs), $read_num);
```

The &read_more() subroutine works with one or two arguments, but here's the two argument version:

```
if (@_ == 2) {
        # if an empty string was passed
        if ( $_[1] eq "" ) {
                $_[1] = 0;
        }

        # print $_[1] headers behind $_[0]
        foreach ( ($_[0]-$_[1])..($_[0]-1) ) {

                my $from = $imap->get_header ($_, "from");
                my $subject = $imap->get_header ($_, "subject");

                (printf "%d: %s\n", $_, $from);
                (printf "%d: %s\n\n", $_, $subject);
         }
}
```

So, if I called `&read_more(1000, 5)`, I would see "Subject" and "From" header fields for message IDs 990-999. So when I call `&read_more(scalar(@msgIDs), $read_num)`, I intend to see the header fields for the `$read_num` latest messages. Instead, I DO NOT see any header fields for my 9 latest messages, even though I am able to read them perfectly fine in the program (I'm not showing the code for that; it would complicate things). The number of messages found doesn't change. If I received one new message, then I wouldn't be able to see the 10 latest messages. The client is stuck at message ID 1193. I already configured my Gmail settings to allow IMAP. 
 Is this an error in my code, or is it a problem with my Gmail configuration, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you consider @msgID as a sequence starting with 0 and ending with message_count-1. This don't need to be the case. For instance I have currently one message but the msgID of this single message is 6. Therefore you should use the msgIDs given by search and not assume just a simple sequence.

Edit: the code uses Uid =>1 in the constructor, so search returns UIDs and get_header expectets UIDs. Changing it to Uid => 0 makes it work with sequence numbers instead.

Comment: Message ids are continuous in IMAP, or is the perl module using UIDs behind the scenes?

Comment: My options for the module are using UIDs, and a lot of subroutines depend on that, so I can't change it.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich: I understand, but `$imap->search ("ALL")` returns an array (or an array reference, but that's another story) that lists the message IDs. I tried to use this array is scalar context, would give me the number of elements in the array, which SHOULD be the number of messages. But it is not, causing the problem.

Comment: I think I've found the real problem: you set in the constructor Uid =>1, which means, that search, get_header etc all work on UID and no sequence numbers. Changing it to Uid => 0 uses sequence numbers instead.

Comment: After some more hours of deception and many tears, I believe you are right, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself. Okay, this requires a bit of faulty logic (this program is for personal use, anyway, so that doesn't matter). 
If a email doesn't have a "From" header field in its header (that is, if a email is found without an author), than it isn't an email. So, a subroutine that can count emails until an empty "From" header field is found would correctly count the number of emails in the Inbox:

```
# the only argument is the IMAP object, that allows communication
sub message_num {

        # there's always going to be at least this many messages, so guess here
        my @guess = $_[0]->search("ALL");

        # get the guess in scalar format so we can count with it
        my $i = scalar (@guess);

        # while the "from" headers are defined
        while ( defined ($_[0]->get_header ($i, "from")) ) {
                # count the messages past what the guess said
                $i++;
        }

        # return that count
        $i;
}
```

So, calling `&message_num ($imap)` in my code gives me a usable number of messages. It's incorrect, but it allows me to see all of my recent messages, which is what I wanted.

Comment: If anyone has any methods to get the TRUE amount of messages, I'd truly appreciate it.